# Is there a "Do Not Annoy" me with the Cookie Law HTTP header?

Tags: http, cookies, rfc, do-not-track

The `DNT` ([Do Not Track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track)) HTTP header allows a browser to let a webserver know that the user does not wish to be tracked. Is there an equivalent `DNA` (Do Not Annoy me with the [cookie law](https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/) warning) HTTP header? Since all websites nowadays display a message that essentially says "accept our cookies or GTFO", I feel it only serves as an example of [alarm fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alarm_fatigue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/725312/disable-all-cookie-warnings-and-hints) in the past.

There are many interesting answers in that thread so I'd suggest you to read it. There is not official way to disable cookie warnings but there are certain extension that lets you avoid some.

Here's a link to one of those extensions: [I don't care about cookies](http://www.kiboke-studio.hr/i-dont-care-about-cookies/)